# How to show new line with numbers format from server response of String in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, newline

I am getting server response as "We've organizations in following something locations. 1. First test 2. Second test 3. Third test 4. Fourth test. Choose one for more information";

I am working on **Objective-C** and trying to showing in UILabel, but issue is I want to show as Paragraph. Like splitting the string by following.

We've organizations in following something locations.

1. First test
2. Second test
3. Third test
4. Fourth test
   Choose one for more information.

The above one is example, but the data is completely dynamic and no idea about how many points would be there in response string.

Anyone have idea about this.

Comment: It seems quite easy.  Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: How to do split the string data? and how to show again in label? I have idea componentseperatedbystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, here it is. This may helps someone in future.

```
    NSArray *pointsArray = [trimmedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *strOccurence, *strReplacing;
    for (int i=1; i<pointsArray.count; i++){
        strOccurence = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.",i];
        strReplacing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%d.",i];
        trimmedString = [trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:strOccurence withString:strReplacing];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text  = trimmedString;
```

Comment: which  answer is suitable for accept then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
       NSString *str = @"We've organizations in following something locations. 1. First test 2. Second test 3. Third test 4. Fourth test.";
       str =  [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1." withString:@"\n 1."];
       str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"2" withString:@"\n 2"];
       str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3" withString:@"\n 3"];
       str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"4" withString:@"\n 4"];
       yourlbl.text = str;
```

**Dynamic way**

```
NSString *str = @"We've organizations in following something locations. 1. First test 2. Second test 3. Third test 4. Fourth test.";
    NSCharacterSet *numberCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
        // Eat non-digits and negative sign
        [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numberCharset
                                   intoString:NULL];
        int aInt;
        if ([theScanner scanInt:&aInt]) {
         str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aInt] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %d",aInt]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above one is example, but the data is completely dynamic and no idea about how many points would be there in response string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First test",@"Second test",@"Third test" , @"Fourth test Choose one for more information.", nil];

 __block NSString *strConcate = [NSString new];
 [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

      strConcate = [strConcate stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu. %@\n",(unsigned long)(idx + 1),obj]];
 }];

 self.labelString.text = strConcate;
```

Comment: @Pratike Lad, this will work for multiple string, but I have only one string. In this use case, this logic not working.